# Почему кнопка удаляется с панели, но новая не появляется?

Tags: java, swing

К примеру есть 3 класса: `MainClass` (запускает приложение), `MainFrame` (тут главный фрейм) и `Buttons` (тут соответственно кнопки).

```
  
public class MainClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater( 
        new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
                 new MainFrame();
             }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private Buttons b1, b2;
    private JPanel panel;

    public MainFrame() {
        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        b1 = new Buttons("b1");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                panel.remove(b1);
                repaint();
                    b2 = new Buttons("b2");
                    panel.add(b2);
                }
            });
        panel.add(b1);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
    }
}
```

```java
 public class Buttons extends JButton{
    public Buttons(String s) {
        //super(s);
        setText(s);
        setVisible(true);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,75));
    }
}
```

Вопрос: при нажатии на кнопку она удаляется, но вторая кнопка сразу не появляется, однако если свернуть окно и потом восстановить, вторая кнопка появляется, как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Всё просто.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        panel.remove(b1);
                        b2 = new Buttons("b2");
                        panel.add(b2);
                        revalidate();
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Да)) Как говориться: всё гениальное - просто!))
Благодарю!